# Unable to maintain connection on servers. Ping inconsistent

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, ping

We have two new Windows 2012 server installs. These are fresh installs that don't have much on them. However, they are having connection issues with the SQL server. From the SQL server I have some command prompts pinging the new servers.

When I ping 192.68.1.143 from the SQL server, I get the following result. It says unreachable. During the example below, I opened a Windows Explorer window (from 192.168.1.143) and typed \192.168.1.201... then, it made connection and replied with pings... After a bit, it went back to unreachable. This behavior is repeatable.

All other computers on the network are behaving well... just these two servers are not. What might be causing this?

Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time=1246ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.143: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.201: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.143:
    Packets: Sent = 154, Received = 150, Lost = 4 (2% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1246ms, Average = 73ms
Control-C

Comment: You have a networking issue but haven't described the network configuration...

Comment: You also haven't described the specific SQL connectivity problem either.

Comment: Set firewalls on the Windows servers off to test if that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure all ethernet cables are securely connected, try swapping out the ethernet cable on hosts you think are being problematic. I've run into this before with a windows box, connectivity would come and go, and I found my ethernet cable wasn't seated firmly. Worth a shot.